# Why does chrome.storage.local.get cause an XML page to crash?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, local-storage

I am developing a Google chrome extension. Everything works fine except that the extension causes the page to crash when viewing an XML file (such as a Site Map).

I have narrowed the issue down to using chrome.storage.local and the problem does not occur when that is taken out.

I realize this isn't a major problem as XML files are only rarely viewed in a browser by most people but, as a developer, I often view Site Maps and other XML files and it is really bugging me.

I have not been able to find any other info about this on google. Is this a bug with chrome.storage or could it be something else entirely?

Thanks,

Comment: Sounds like a bug. Please create a minimal test case, and submit a bug to http://new.crbug.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have submitted a bug report: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=151838&q=chrome.storage%20XML&colspec=ID%20Pri%20Mstone%20ReleaseBlock%20OS%20Area%20Feature%20Status%20Owner%20Summary

In the mean-time, I am using this code as a work around:

```
var isXML = new RegExp(".+\\.[Xx][Mm][Ll](\\?|$)", "i").test(window.location.href);
if (isXML == false) { RunExtension(); }
```

Hope this helps someone else.

Comment: The URL is not a good way to detect XML. You could use `if (document.doctype !== null) RunExtension();` instead.

Comment: @RobW Wouldn't that just check that the doctype is set, rather than what it is set to? Also would it work if a page didn't declare the doctype?

Comment: Yes to "check that doctype is set". But checking the end of an URL is still quite weak. When viewing the generated source of a XML file, I notice that Chrome inserts a stylesheet with ID xml-viewer-style. So, the check could be `if (!document.getElementById('xml-viewer-style')) {RunExtension();}`.

Comment: Yes, I agree checking the url is weak, (I couldn't think of a better work around) for example it would fail if the default document was an xml file, but when does that happen anyway? Its rare enough that "normal" users view xml code. 

Good spot on the 'xml-viewer-style', I like that a lot. If you would care to write it out as an answer, I will mark it as correct. Thanks for your help.

Comment: While my comment is helpful, it does not answer the question, hence the comment.

Comment: The question was "Is this a bug with chrome.storage or could it be something else entirely?" Your answer was that its probably a bug and that I should report it and here is a work around until its fixed. I can't think of a better answer. I'll leave it up to you but thank you very much for your help anyway :-)